# Does any Biblical basis exist for a year to be called a day?

Tags: exegesis, biblical-basis, terminology

According to Peter 3:8, thousand years is like only one day for God:

> But do not forget this one thing, dear friends: With the Lord a day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years are like a day.

Thus, God has the  broadest scope of history than anybody else; which also Isaiah alluded to:

> “As the heavens are higher than the earth, so are my ways higher than your ways and my thoughts than your thoughts. (55:9)

Acknowledging that we come up short in comparison with the wiser spiritual entity we call God, I am asking: does any Biblical basis exist for a year to be called a day?

Comment: As you say, God is He who sees such things, expanded or compressed, such is His Divinity. There is no text I know of that encourages humanity to do likewise, since we cannot. The term 'day' may mean, in certain contexts, a considerable amount of time, idiomatically (_Abraham rejoiced to see my day_). But I am unclear as to what you are actually suggesting. So I think some detail and clarity would be helpful. (I have edited, only to turn your question into a question on the header.)

Comment: **And God said, Let there be lights in the firmament of the heaven to divide the day from the night; and let them be for signs, and for seasons, and for days, and years:** [Genesis 1:14](https://biblehub.com/genesis/1-14.htm)

Comment: The concept of a day for a year in the interpretation of prophecy exists. The two main scriptural basis are numbers14:34. Ezekiel 4:6

Comment: The 6 days of creation doesn’t necessarily have to have been literal  days. They could have been terra-forming trips from the future. Poetically renditioned.

Answer (score 3):

2 Peter 3:8 likens a day to a thousand years in the sight of God.  A similar expression is found in Psalm 90:4:

> For a thousand years in your sight are like a day that has just gone by, or like a watch in the night.

***Neither passage is saying a year is a thousand years***, only that when viewed in the light of eternity, it could be likened to a thousand years, or even “a watch in the night” which is but a few hours.  The Jews divided the night into three watches (Judges 7:19; 1 Samuel 11:11) but the Romans had four night watches, each lasting three hours (Matthew 14:25).

There are other biblical examples that illustrate how time can be viewed.  “The day of the Lord” (1 Thessalonians 5) is not a literal 24-hour day.  It is an unspecified period of time.

We are still in the seventh day after God finished his work of creation, His day of rest (Genesis 2:1-3).

Jesus, quoting from Isaiah 61:1, spoke of “the year of the Lord’s favour” (Luke 4:19).  That “year” is still with us.

God, as the creator of time, does not view time as mortal humans view time.  Our allocated “three score years and ten” are but a fleeting moment.  ***God stands above time***, and He waits patiently for humans to repent and turn to Him (2 Peter 3:9).

There is, however, a danger in taking the expression “a day is like a thousand years” and applying it literally to biblical chronology.  Some denominations have used this as a means of measuring time in order to predict the tribulation period or the second coming of Christ Jesus.  No man knows the day or the hour when He will return to bring judgment on God’s enemies.  The day of the Lord will come like a thief in the night (2 Peter 3:10) when people least expect it.

***“A day is like a thousand years” is a figure of speech*** which makes a description more emphatic or vivid.  The expression simply brings home the fact that God, the Alpha and the Omega, the beginning and the end, sees time through the eyes of eternity, and not through the eyes of human experience.

Comment: Up-voted +1, but some would say that the 'rest' of the seventh day, of the first creation, has been interrupted by Adam's transgression, thus Jesus says '_my Father worketh hitherto, and I work_' being the work of a New Creation unto an eternal rest.